# How to create a LLVM Module from a source file or translation unit

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I'm trying to create a Module object representing IR of a c source file but I don't know how to proceed.
I'm able to create a translation unit or AST from a souce file but I need to access the module Object containing that data.
In the Module class the constructor doesn't allow to take a path as parameter.

Do somebody have any idea how to do that? or a tutorial which does something similar?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462456/method-to-create-llvm-ir