# Generating LLVM-IR in standalone process using C++

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

In my project work, I have been working on developing a language server to perform static analysis on the C/C++ source code. This process requires LLVM-IR which is analysed to perform static analysis checks.
I have been using the below command to generate the LLVM-IR code for my C/C++ program. Which is hard coded and called via system() command.

`clang -O3 -emit-llvm hello.c -c -o hello.bc`.

This above usage opens for security vulnerability, hence needs to be avoid. My current task is to use the C/C++ API provided by the LLVM infrastructure to convert source file to LLVM-IR in the standalone process.

Being new to the LLVM repository, I am finding hard to find the API usage and example program for the same. I would appreciate if anyone would help how to proceed in solving the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [exevp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that's still what I am not looking for. I looking for sample code implementation to generate LLVM-IR.

Comment: I have also referred to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316529/generating-ir-from-clang-using-classes, But have not found any answers yet.