# Get constexpr without running the program

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have a library (both as source and compiled) and I'm writing a program (not linked to this library) that needs to know if some type in the library is e.g. trivially copyable or not.

I could make my program write the following into file.cpp:

```
#include "mylibrary.hpp"
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<B>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<C>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<D>::value << '\n';
}
```

then compile and run this code and parse the output. Is there a better way to get this information? (performance is important). Can libclang do that?

UPDATE because of comments:

Regarding the XY problem:
What I'm trying to do, is write a program (called rust-bindgen) in rust, that gets the path of a C++ header file as am argument and generates rust-c++ bindings for that header file.
I need to generating the bindings differently depending on whether the type is trivially copyable/relocatable.

So I have a path to a C++ header file and I need to know whether a given type that is defined in that header file is trivially copyable.
The approach above works, but is slow, because it involves compiling file.cpp.

TLDR:
How can I write a fast rust function, that takes two strings as an argument and returns a bool: The first string is the path to a C++ header file, the second string is the name of a type defined in said header file. It should return a bool that says whether the type is trivially copyable or not.

Comment: This post really is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You haven't described your original problem in detail, and instead focused the post on a solution that isn't good enough. It'd be better to show us how you intend to use those values to get a good answer that fits you.

Comment: Not sure to understand... the problem is that you need to know, in a program that doesn't link the library, if some types in the library are trivially copyable?

Comment: so what's the problem? [is_trivially_copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) may be used with `constexpr` ([an example](https://godbolt.org/z/3WaGEb))

Comment: your code is as performant as either `std::cout << true << '\n';` or `std::cout << false << '\n';`. Its not quite clear what you want to do. You need that information at compile time?

Comment: I updated my post. It should be clearer now.

Comment: @Kryptomatrix `is slow, because it involves compiling` Well, it *is* the compiler which evaluates a `constexpr`, so you can't avoid compiling (unless you want to write your own C++ compiler).

Comment: @dxiv The question is if there is a C++ parser (maybe libclang) that can evaluate this constexpr without doing the complete compiling process.

Comment: @Kryptomatrix Doubt it. That's definitely not evaluated in the parsing phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to compile the code, at least to IR. This is because the triviality of a C++ class can depend on an arbitrarily complicated computation whose inputs may include platform attributes, available headers, preprocessor defines, compiler options etc., which can thus only be carried out by a C++ compiler.

If you are invoking clang as a binary the option to emit IR is `clang -S -emit-llvm` and you will then want to parse the LLVM IR output; for example for

```
#include <type_traits>
struct A {};
struct B { B(B const&); };
struct C { ~C(); };
struct D { D(D const&) = default; };
int a = std::is_trivially_copyable<A>::value;
int b = std::is_trivially_copyable<B>::value;
int c = std::is_trivially_copyable<C>::value;
int d = std::is_trivially_copyable<D>::value;
```

the IR is:

```
@a = dso_local local_unnamed_addr global i32 1, align 4, !dbg !0
@b = dso_local local_unnamed_addr global i32 0, align 4, !dbg !6
@c = dso_local local_unnamed_addr global i32 0, align 4, !dbg !10
@d = dso_local local_unnamed_addr global i32 1, align 4, !dbg !12
 ^ variable name                             ^ initializer
```

If you want to use libclang, you will need to invoke [EmitLLVMOnlyAction](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1EmitLLVMOnlyAction.html) giving a [Module](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html) which you can then extract the GlobalVariable definitions from. See: [Method to create LLVM IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462456/method-to-create-llvm-ir)